# What is the use of ., in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Why is a comma used after the period in certain XPath expressions? Here is an example:

```
Set nlist = doc.selectNodes("//book/author/first-name[starts-with(.,'M')]")
```

I tried to search for this with Google, but the literal `""` operators don't seem to like periods or commas.

Comment: Period `.` is the abbreviated syntax version of `self::node()`

Comment: @jasso: current node (`self::node()`) is not the same as the context node (`.`).

Comment: @empo: As a *location step* `.` is same as `self::node()`, this is clearly stated in the XPath recommendation. `self::node()` is not (necessarily) the same node as returned by the XSLT function `current()`, if that is what you meant to refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath the `.` mark stands for *context node*. The *context node* is usually the same of the *current node* (`current()` function) being processed but it might be situations where it's different. This is not really obvious when you deal with XPath only, but it happens when using XSLT. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath) in SO explaining such a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the dot a wildcard or a special keyword ? What are the other things we can pass to the function instead of the dot ?

Answer (score 3):

`starts-with` has two parameters and returns true if the first parameter ends with the string from second parameter, otherwise it returns false.

If the first parameter is `.` it means the current item. You can find more about other XPath punctuation marks [here](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xpath-punctuation-part-1).

Answer (score 1):

The `.` stands for "current node", the `,` is a normal parameter separator.

So, the parameters being sent to the [`starts-with`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example8.html) function are a `.` (current node) and `'M'`.

Comment: The `.` normally coincides with the current node, but it is not the current node.