# How to find element that matches xslt attribute value in for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<data>
  <foos>
    <foo id="1" checked="yes" />
    <foo id="2" />
    <foo id="3" />
    <foo id="4" checked="yes" />
  </foos>
  <bars>
    <bar for="1" name="blub" />
    <bar for="2" name="bla" />
    <bar for="3" name="baz" />
    <bar for="4" name="plim" />
  </bars>
</data>
```

Now I want to print all the `name` attributes of those element `bar` which point to an element `foo` that has the attribute `checked`. So for the example above, my xslt would output `blub` and `plim`.

Here is what I have tried so far is to just check whether I can print the `id` attribute of the `foo` element that each `bar` belongs to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//bars/bar">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../foos/foo[@id=./@for]/@id" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but to no avail. I think the problem is, that the check `foo[@id=./@for]` will select both `@id` and `@for` from the `foo` element. So how can I say that I want the `@for` attribute from my current element in the for loop but the `@id` from the *other* current element?

Comment: If you're working with HTML then say so - this example isn't XML because XML doesn't allow an attribute name like `checked` without a value.  I assume that in the real data `foo` is an `input type="checkbox"` and `bar` is `label`?

Comment: @IanRoberts thanks, I didn't know and added the attribute value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how can I say that I want the `@for` attribute from my current element in the for loop but the `@id` from the *other* current element?

Use [the `current()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current):

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../foos/foo[@id=current()/@for]/@id" />
```

Inside the square brackets, `.` is the node that the predicate is testing, whereas `current()` is the node that is the current target of the `for-each`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative that should also improve performance you can define a key

```
<xsl:key name="foo-by-id" match="foos/foo" use="@id"/>
```

and then replace

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//bars/bar">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../foos/foo[@id=./@for]/@id" />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

with

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//bars/bar">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('foo-by-id', @for)/@id" />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the `xsl:key` idea from @martin-honnen, make a key for the checked items:

```
<xsl:key name="checked" match="foos/foo[@checked = 'yes']" use="@id" />
```

Then your XSLT can become:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/bars/bar[key('checked', @for)]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
</xsl:template>
```

Only the `foo` with `checked="yes"` are included in the `checked` key (though if you are working from HTML, it's more likely that it's `checked="checked"`).  `key('checked', @for)` for an element without a corresponding `checked="yes"` will return an empty node-set/empty sequence (depending on your XSLT version), so for those elements, the predicate will evaluate to `false`, so the `xsl:apply-templates` selects only the elements that you are interested in, so the template for `bar` becomes very simple.