# Can I select a div by value in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8.1, html-agility-pack

I have a `div` without `id` or `class` that I need to select. I'd like to do that by value (since the only way I can think of to get it):

```
<div style=""> foo: baa </div>
```

How can I do that?

Imagine XPath query: `//div[contains(@innerText,'foo:')]`

Comment: There are plenty of similar questions - you probably looking for "how to pass current node to XPath function" ("."/"self"/"current()") - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
//div[contains(.,'foo:')]
```