# Why XSLT template not working?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file in some format and want to convert it into another format.

The first format is :

```
<Project>
 <Requirements>
  <Source>     
    <Section>
      <Requirement>
        <Content>
          this is I<sub>leakage</sub>
        </Content>
        <Title></Title>
        <Property name="Status"/>
      </Requirement>
   </Section>
  </Source>
 </Requirements>
</Project>
```

And I'm using a template to change this sub tags into subscript tags

```
      this is I<sub>leakage</sub>
```

to

```
      this is I<subscript>leakage</subscript>
```

and I'm using this template to convert:

```
<xsl:template match="sub">
   <Subscript>
       <xsl:value-of select="current()/text()"/>
   </Subscript>
</xsl:template>
```

problem is the template isn't working , Although if I put the sub tags out side the Requirement(for example under Section) it works fine.

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: If it works when you move the `sub` tags out of `Requirement`, something isn't getting processed. You need to show more of your XSLT. (A working example at least.)

Comment: To say that in another way, there is probably no apply-templates instruction that selects the sub elements for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
<xsl:template match="sub">
 <Subscript>
  <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
 </Subscript>
</xsl:template>
```

This worked at my end. Reason for difference can be found here:
[Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath)

Comment: "*This worked at my end.*" Did OP's version NOT work at your end?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, But I'm afraid it didn't help in solving this issue , it seems like something blocking this template from working inside the Requirement block

Comment: Kindly post your full xslt