# Attributes as arguments return empty values in xsl:contains() in XSLT

Tags: xslt

The variable $authors is declared as follows:

```
<listAuthor>
    <author catalogNumber="26A.18.1" fullName="Pjotr Domanski"/>
    <author catalogNumber="26A.19.1" fullName="Hermine Rex"/>
    <author catalogNumber="26A.19.2" fullName="Christoferus Hohenzell"/>
</listAuthor>
```

Further, the following XML input is given:

```
<h1:Block Type="obj">
  <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="77772001" />
  <h1:Field Type="5209" Value="26A.19.1 : Lazy Tennis"/>
</h1:Block>
```

The expected output is:

```
<h1:Block Type="obj">
  <h1:Field Type="5000" Value="77772001" />
  <h1:Field Type="5209" Value="26A.19.1 : Lazy Tennis"/>
  <h1:Field Type="9904" Value="Hermine Rex"/>
</h1:Block>
```

Here is a snippet of my transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="h1:Block">
    <h1:Block Type="obj">
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::*"/>
        <h1:Field Type="9904">
            <xsl:attribute name="Value"
               select="$authors/listAuthor/author[contains (h1:Field[@Type='5209']/@Value, @catalogNumber)]/@fullName"/>
        </h1:Field>
    </h1:Block>
</xsl:template>
```

The name of the author should be put in **h1:Field[@Type='9904']/@Value**, when **@catalogNumber** in **$authors/author** is contained in  **h1:Field[@Type='5209']**. Unfortunately, the attribute **@Value** remains empty.

I found the following workaround by introducing a variable:

```
<xsl:template match="h1:Block">
    <h1:Block Type="obj">
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="value5209" select="h1:Field[@Type='5209']/@Value"/>
        <h1:Field Type="9904">
            <xsl:attribute name="Value"
               select="$authors/listAuthor/author[contains ($value5209, @catalogNumber)]/@fullName"/>
        </h1:Field>
    </h1:Block>
</xsl:template>
```

In this case, it works fine. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work in the first case? I use Saxon Saxon-HE 9.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the predicate the context node is the `author` element which does not have a `h1:Field`, so change `$authors/listAuthor/author[contains (h1:Field[@Type='5209']/@Value, @catalogNumber)]/@fullName` to `$authors/listAuthor/author[contains (current()/h1:Field[@Type='5209']/@Value, @catalogNumber)]/@fullName` to select the context node of the template.

Comment: **It works**. Thanks so much! The difference between context node and current node is explained in [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath