# Selenium webdriver Need to check a checkbox

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to check a checkbox called standards,

please see screenshot.

[image]

I was able to expand the `information type` dropdown via:

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'expand') and h3[contains(text(), 'Information Type')]]")
```

Comment: I was able to expand the information type dropdown via: By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'expand') and h3[contains(text(), 'Information Type')]]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expand `Information Type` element you should wait until `Standards` check box element getting visible and clickable using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//li[normalize-space(.)='Standards']/input"))).click();
```

You can also use this `xpath` as well :

```
.//li[contains(.,'Standards')]/input
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more about the xpath expression: .//li[normalize-space(.)='Standards']/input? I am a bit lost. Why do you need /input at the end? Thanks

Comment: Also why do you need .// instead of // at the front?

Comment: `//li[normalize-space(.)='Standards']` this just returns `li` element with `input` element child so again `/input` gives me desire element which contain `Standards` text.

Comment: You can use both `.//` and `//` here, `.` just determine in which context you want to search for  the element. But here `.` doesn't play any role here because you're searching element on whole page context, it just for best practice if some time if you to get desire element some thing like as `driver.findElement("//li[normalize-space(.)='Standards']").findElement(".//input"));`  here using `.` would search`input` element only first found `li` element context instead of whole page context. Thanks

Comment: @Tony For more details [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath)