# Xpath with scrapy: I get everything hundred times

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy 1.2 with Xpath (and of course: python 3.4) to read the Hot 100 chart on billboard.com. I get all 100 titles for each song when I use the second option in the code. I get that's because of the double /; but I cannot make the first option work. How can I make sure that I get only the right title for each song?

```
class MusicalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "musicalspider"
    allowed_domains = ["billboard.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/']

    def parse(self, response):
        songs = response.xpath('//div[@class="chart-data js-chart-data"]/div[@class="container"]/article')

        for song in songs:
            item = MusicItem()
            # first option:
            item['title'] = song.xpath('div[@class="chart-row__primary"]/div[@class="chart-row__main-display"]/div[@class="chart-row__container"]/div[@class="chart-row__title"]/h2[@class="chart-row__song"]').extract()
            # second option:
            item['title'] = song.xpath('//h2[@class="chart-row__song"]').extract()

            yield item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a common problem. Remember to start your inner-loop XPath expressions with a dot - this would make them *context-specific*:

```
for song in songs:
    item = MusicItem()
    # first option:
    item['title'] = song.xpath('.//div[@class="chart-row__primary"]/div[@class="chart-row__main-display"]/div[@class="chart-row__container"]/div[@class="chart-row__title"]/h2[@class="chart-row__song"]').extract()
    # second option:
    item['title'] = song.xpath('.//h2[@class="chart-row__song"]').extract()

    yield item
```

See more at:

- [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath)

---

Here is the spider that works for me:

```
import scrapy

class MusicalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "musicalspider"
    allowed_domains = ["billboard.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/']

    def parse(self, response):
        songs = response.xpath('//div[@class="chart-data js-chart-data"]/div[@class="container"]/article')

        for song in songs:
            item = MusicItem()
            item['title'] = song.xpath('.//h2[@class="chart-row__song"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield item
```

It produces the following items:

```
{'title': u'Black Beatles'}
{'title': u'Closer'}
...
{'title': u'Hold Up'}
{'title': u'Gangsta'}
```

Comment: No, both of your options give me empty lists

Comment: @user7162453: Answer is essentially correct, but your XPaths may have additional problems.

Comment: @user7162453 the idea is correct, the xpath expressions themselves should probably be adjusted, let me test that.

Comment: @user7162453 okay, I've updated the answer and posted the spider I'm currently running and the output items. Check it out, hope that helps.