# What is the xpath to find all Anchor Elements inside another Element?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a problem with locating a certain element using xpath in WebDriver. Below is my approach:

Scenario 1:
Below finds all anchor Elements whose 'href' contains value provided. Using this approach I am able to locate 38 Elements. Agreed. Works as expected.      `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://www.holidayiq.com/hotels/')]"));`

Scenario 2: I first locate a class named 'Rank-bar' which is available only once. I then use the same xpath to locate all anchor tags within this class only. Expected anchor tags is 4 However, I still find 38 Elements using this approach as well.

```
WebElement elements2 = driver.findElement(By.className("rank-bar"));
elements2.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://www.holidayiq.com/hotels/')]"));
```

What is that I am doing wrong here? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are again searching to find `anchor` element on whole document context that's why you are finding same.

If you want to search `anchor` element on `elements2` context, [you need to search with `.//` `xpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath) as below :-

```
elements2.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'http://www.holidayiq.com/hotels/')]"));
```

Or you can find same thing in just on liner using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rank-bar a[href*='http://www.holidayiq.com/hotels/']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should build a direct xpath like this:

```
//*[@class='rank-bar']//a[contains(@href, 'http://www.holidayiq.com/hotels')]
```

as you see you are used contains, this means you could also have something like:

```
//*[@class='rank-bar']//a[contains(@href, 'holidayiq.com/hotels')]
```

and find the elements from one step like:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='rank-bar']//a[contains(@href, 'holidayiq.com/hotels')]"));
```