# xpath ".//span", what does the dot mean?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In `//header[.//span[contains(text(), 'part_title')]]//label[contains(@class, 'start')]`, what does the `.` dot in `.//` mean?

Comment: Have you learned about XPath syntax yet? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to learn about the concept of the XPath "context" node.  When navigating an XPath expression, every step identifies a context node or node-set from which the subsequent expression is evaluated, except for absolute paths such as `//`.

The construction `.//span` means "starting at the current node find the next descendant `span` at any level below the current context node.  Contrast with `./span`, which would mean an immediate child `span` of the current context node.

Without the leading dot `/span` means the root node if it's a `span`, and `//span` means the first `span` in the document at any level.

Or, to put it more simply, the leading dot has exactly the same meaning as the `.` entry in a Linux directory.

Comment: This is correct (+1).  See also [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/290085)