# Python: Xpath Issue getting value for each DIV in a For loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath

I'm using Python 3.6 to process a chunk of HTML, the issue I'm having is that the code below for the loop is working but the `atag.xpath` query is searching the whole HTML source and returning all four tag values for `data-size`.

What I'm trying to do is that when `PAGE_RAW`is processed for the `for` loop that for every instance of a DIV containing a class of `item` that it will find the child DIV with a class of `padding` and pull out the `data-size` attribute for that one tag and not all the tags if finds in the HTML source.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="padding" data-size="12"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="padding" data-size="13"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="padding" data-size="14"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="padding" data-size="15"></div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
import lxml.html as LH
...

PAGE_RAW = driver.page_source
PAGE_RAW = LH.fromstring(PAGE_RAW)

for atag in PAGE_RAW.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'item')]"):
    data = atag.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'padding')]/@data-size")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're facing here is that in your second xpath, the `//` is telling it to search **anywhere** in the document (it doesn't matter if the current node is a specific `div`, it always searches from start).

To find any nodes under the current node, replace `//` with `.//` (the `.` indicates that the search starts with the current node, not the root).

```
import lxml.html as LH
...

PAGE_RAW = driver.page_source
PAGE_RAW = LH.fromstring(PAGE_RAW)

for atag in PAGE_RAW.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'item')]"):
    data = atag.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'padding')]/@data-size")
```

Comment: Whats the difference between `.//` and `./` or is there any?

Comment: While `.//` will match any descendants (or self), `./` will match only children.

Comment: Check out the second answer here, it's well explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath