# Finding specific XPath given ID and div?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have a table of names and each of the names can be accessed by the following XPath: `//*[@id="right_pane"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[INDEX]/td[2]` where index is a number. What's the best way to search for these XPaths while using Selenium? My current solution is the following:

1. Replace INDEX with 0
2. Search for element
3. Check if element is the correct one
4. Increment INDEX and repeat

The process above seems inefficient as the starting index varies (I start at 0 but it's possible the first entry in the table starts at index 200) and searching for each element takes up to  seconds (using an implicit wait until in selenium).

Is there a better approach to this problem? Or am I stuck searching 1 by 1?

Comment: Share HTML sample for the same

Comment: I am sure there is a better approach but we can't really guess at what that might be. If you shared a link to the page or at least some of the relevant HTML we could give you an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the page as it's set up locally only at the momemt

Comment: So your essentially waiting for an exception to be thrown and catching it when it fails to find each of the elements until the index exists? It would be better to use a general selector to return each row as a list of webelements, and then use those to iterate over... Or better yet, have a specific test case that is searching for something specific, instead of trying to test everything on the page (**too clever**). Then you could have a method that returns the webelement based on some text, or class, or value, etc...

Comment: Currently I implicitly waiting till I find the first element, then I don't implicitly wait for the rest till I find what I'm looking for. It's not ideal but it's the best that I've come up with. I can't test for a specific element unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating explicitly over multiple values for INDEX,

```
//*[@id="right_pane"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[INDEX]/td[2]
```

replace INDEX with your test.  For example, if you want the second `td` for the `tr` whose first `td` is `"foo"`:

```
//*[@id="right_pane"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[td[1]="foo"]/td[2]
```

Comment: What does the `td[1]` bit equate to? I thought that it would be something more like `[.//td[1]='foo']` to indicate that it is a child of the `tr` given the relative reference, `.//`.

Comment: `[td[1]='foo']` is all that's needed.  `[./td[1]='foo']`  would be redundant.  And if you don't know the difference between `/` and `//`, see  [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath).

Comment: So basically `./` is implied in the syntax `[td[1]="foo"]`. That's what I was looking for. Thanks