# Incorrectly extracting repeated values from list of XML objects in R

Tags: r, xml-parsing, lapply

I'm having a problem using `lapply` and `xml_find_first` from the `xml2` package to pull nodes from a list of xml objects. I'm pulling a few thousand records from the Scopus API. Since I can only get 25 records at a time, I run it so I get a list with 100+ elements of 25 records each. I know a few of the records have missing values, so my goal is to shuffle things around until I get a list were each record is its own element, then use `lapply` and `xml_find_first` so that I'll get null values where appropriate. The problem is that I end up pulling repeated values as if everything is still nested in their initial lists.

Here's a reproducible example with a list of 2 elements with 2 records each, with `citedby-count` missing from the last one:

````
```{r}
library(xml2)

# Simulate how data come in from Scopus
# Build 2 list elements, 2 entries each
el1 <- read_xml(
"<feed>
  <blah>Bunch of stuff I don't need</blah>
  <blah>Bunch of other stuff I don't need</blah>
  <entry>
    <eid>2-s2.0-1542382496</eid>
    <citedby-count>9385</citedby-count>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <eid>2-s2.0-0032721879</eid>
    <citedby-count>4040</citedby-count>
  </entry>
</feed>"
)
el2 <- read_xml( # This one's missing citedby-count for last entry
"<feed>
  <blah>Bunch of stuff I don't need</blah>
  <blah>Bunch of other stuff I don't need</blah>
  <entry>
    <eid>2-s2.0-0041751098</eid>
    <citedby-count>3793</citedby-count>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <eid>2-s2.0-73449149291</eid>
  </entry>
</feed>"
)
# Combine into list
lst <- list(el1,el2)
# Check
lst
```
````

This gives me:

[image]

My goal is to pull out the entries so they are list items. This way, `xml_find_first` should stick a null value in for the entry where `citedby-count` is missing.

````
```{r}
# Pull entry nodes
lst2 <- lapply(lst, xml_find_all, "//entry")
# Unlist
lst2 <- unlist(lst2, recursive=FALSE)
# Check - each entry is its own element
lst2
```
````

[image]

The hangup is when I try to extract a node that I know is missing in some of the entries in a way that will leave a null where it's missing. `xml_find_first` should do that. But...

````
```{r}
cbc <- lapply(lst2, xml_find_first, "//citedby-count")
cbc <- lapply(cbc, xml_text)
cbc # Repeats the first values of original nesting
```
````

[image]

So I checked what would happen with `xml_find_all`:

````
```{r}
cbc2 <- lapply(lst2, xml_find_all, "//citedby-count")
cbc2 <- lapply(cbc2, xml_text)
cbc2 # Elements contain all values from initial nesting
```
````

[image]

Which makes no sense in comparison with the output of `lst2` above. For some reason, pulling the text retains the values from the initial nesting, even though it doesn't show up when looking at the final list of xml objects. I'm stumped.

Comment: To solve your problem use a "." before the //. From the xml2 documentation: "# Note the difference between .// and // # // finds anywhere in the document (ignoring the current node) # .// finds anywhere beneath the current node"

Comment: @Dave2e Oh, wow, I remember reading that weeks ago and it completely slipped my mind. Yep, that worked. If you want to submit as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as @Dave2e comments, do not simply use the "anywhere" XPath search (specifically the descendant-or-self search) with `//` for child elements as the search will run on entire document.

How can this be if I do not explicitly call the original document? If you run `str()` on any of your *xml_find* lists, you will see the object carries `Rcpp` external pointers to the current *node* and *document* available for recall as needed. In fact, I believe the *node* pointer displays when calling the list.

```
str(ls2)    
# List of 4
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ node:<externalptr> 
#   ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"

lst2[[1]]$doc
# <pointer: 0x000000000ca7ff90>

typeof(lst2[[1]]$doc)
# [1] "externalptr"
```

Therefore, be careful of context when searching. You can use the dot prefix (as @Dave2e advises), `.//`, or no slashes at all for retrieval of child elements which here will be equivalent.

```
cbc2 <- lapply(lst2, xml_find_all, "citedby-count")
cbc2 <- lapply(cbc2, xml_text)
cbc2

# [[1]]
# [1] "9385"

# [[2]]
# [1] "4040"

# [[3]]
# [1] "3793"

# [[4]]
# character(0)


cbc2 <- lapply(lst2, xml_find_all, ".//citedby-count")
cbc2 <- lapply(cbc2, xml_text)
cbc2
# [[1]]
# [1] "9385"

# [[2]]
# [1] "4040"

# [[3]]
# [1] "3793"

# [[4]]
# character(0)
```

Do note the `.//` will search ALL descendants (i.e., children, grandchildren, etc.) starting at current node. See [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606964/1422451)