# what does <xsl:apply-templates select=".//text"/>mean in an xsl file

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL file and in this file there are statements:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select=".//text"/>.
```

Can anyone tell me what does `select = ".//" mean`?

I know the '.' is current node, but for'//' is?

Comment: In addition to Martin Honnen's answer, it is also worth pointing out that `text` is not the same as `text()`. Where you see just `text`, that is looking for an element named `text` (e.g. `<text>My text</text>`), whereas `text()` would be looking for text nodes (e.g. just the "My text" bit).

Comment: See also [**What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/290085)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression language in XSLT is XPath and in XPath https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev `//` is an abbreviation for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` so `.//text` is short for `./descendant-or-self::node()/text` which means it selects, relative to the context node, all descendant elements with the name `text`.

Comment: But what descendant elements means?