# Rational Click on Button

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to go through each DIV element, write some data and finally click submit. However, I am not sure why but writing the values and click the submit button is always on the same element.

for example:

```
<div id="random_id" class="section">
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</div>

 <div id="random_id" class="section">
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</div>

<div id="random_id" class="section">
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</div>

<div id="random_id" class="section">
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

I wrote the following python script to loop all sections, fill data inside and click submit.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section']")
for element in elements:
    element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='section']").send_keys("hello world")
    element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='submit']").click()
```

When I run the script, only the first element is filled and clicked for 3 times.

Comment: because you're using the same xpath in the loop. Pretty sure xpath is unique in the whole DOM

Answer (score 0):

Only first element is filled, because when you use `element.child_element` with xpath in Selenium you have to add `./`, `child::tag` or use `descendant::tag` to make it relative to parent, otherwise it's an absolute. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath/35606964).

```
element.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='lastname']")
element.find_element_by_xpath("child::input[@id='lastname']")
element.find_element_by_xpath("descendant::input[@id='lastname']")
```

---

How to do with xpath:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section']")
for element in elements:
    element.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='lastname']").send_keys("hello world")
    element.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='submit']").click()
```

How to do with css selector:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".section")
for element in elements:
    element.find_element_by_css_selector("#lastname").send_keys("hello world")
    element.find_element_by_css_selector("#submit").click()
```

Comment: Why not just suggesting  by 'id' over css_selector in the loop?