# How to restrict findElements method to certain section of web page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please visit link : https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/22408/kxip-vs-dc-13th-match-indian-premier-league-2019

Here I want to print runs scored by individual player from table "Delhi Capitals Innings". I want to restrict the scope to table first and from then use method `findElemets` to get desired output. I am using below code.

If replace

```
System.out.println(table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold']")).get(i).getText());
```

with

```
System.out.println(table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_2']//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr'] //div[@class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold']")).get(i).getText());
```

will get correct result. But I want to do it by limiting the scope of driver.

```
public class Runs{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\ChromeDriver\\1\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/22408/kxip-vs-dc-13th-match-indian-premier-league-2019");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_2']//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr']"));

        int rowCount = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold']")).size();
        for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
            System.out.println(table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold']")).get(i).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below output:

> R
>  15
>  20
>  6
>  39
>  43
>  29
>  1
>  3
>  1
>  0
>   0
>  2
>  3
>  0
>  2
>  0
>  0
>  R
>  0
>  30
>  28
>   39
>  38
>  0
>  2
>  0
>  0
>  4
>  0
>  2
>  4
>  2
>   1
>  0
>  0

It is printing all the elements matching the provided xpath in entire web page. It should print only one present under table "Delhi Capitals Innings".
What I am missing in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path but there is an issue. Generally what you are trying to do is doable. The part you are missing is in the second XPath. A simple HTML `TABLE` example.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To find the `TABLE` using XPath, you would use `//table`. To find a cell in the table using a second locator, you would need to add a `.` to the start of the XPath, e.g. `./tr/td`. This tells XPath to start at the relative position. For more info see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath). The code would be something like

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table"));
WebElement cell = table.findElement(By.xpath("./tr/td"));
                  ^ I'm starting with the table variable here, like you did
                                              ^ but I added the . to indicate relative
```

Having said all of that, it won't work here. There is no single HTML element that encompases all of the "Delhi Capitals Innings" content. There are actually 4 DIVs inside of the parent `DIV` that hold all the content.

```
<div id="innings_2" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr"></div>
    <div class="cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-sub-hdr cb-bg-gray text-bold">Fall of Wickets</div>
    <div class="cb-col cb-col-100 cb-col-rt cb-font-13">...</div>
    <div class="cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr"></div>
</div>
```

You will have to scrape each one separately.

Comment: Is there a similar logic for CSS ? I want to use CSS instead of Xpath.

Comment: @rushikesh Yes, using my `TABLE` example... for the first locator you can use `By.tagName("table")` or `By.cssSelector("table")` and then for the second locator you can use `By.cssSelector("tr td")` or something like that. There is no equivalent `.` notation in CSS selectors like there is in XPath when searching from an element.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method `findelements` to `findelement` in the for loop.

```
System.out.println(table.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-8 text-right text-bold']")).get(i).getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 tables with selector you're using. If you want select only first one use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) below, `[1]` added to the end:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_2']//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr'][1]"));
```

You can get tables by label, [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) below get rows for "Delhi Capitals Innings" table:

```
//span[.='Delhi Capitals Innings']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'cb-ltst-wgt-hdr')]/div[.//a[@class='cb-text-link']]
```

Code:

```
String tableName = "Delhi Capitals Innings";
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='" 
+ tableName + "']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'cb-ltst-wgt-hdr')]/div[.//a[@class='cb-text-link']]"));
```