# how to perform action on WebElement list in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Not able to iterate through WebElement List

Hi

I am doing some action on https://www.makemytrip.com/ under Departure. When click on Departure, it will show calendar of two months.

I am able to get two webElements with same xpath as mentioned below, now I want to go one by one, and `getText()` to match with user month name.

```
List<WebElement> month_list= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Month']"));

ListIterator<WebElement> listIter= month_list.listIterator();

while(listIter.hasNext()) {

WebElement elem= listIter.next();

System.out.println(elem.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']/div")).getText());

}
```

But every time, it is reporting same text :

```
July 2019
July 2019
```

However, I am expecting it should report :

```
July 2019 
August 2019
```

Please guide me how can I perform anything on each element one by one.

[image]

Comment: Please refer the attached image.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `.` instead of `/` in you second `xpath` as below :-

```
System.out.println(elem.findElement(By.xpath("./div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']/div")).getText());
```

**[Absolute vs relative XPaths (/ vs .)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath)**

- `/` introduces an absolute location path, starting at the root of the document.
- `.` introduces a relative location path, starting at the context node.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of **foreach loop**.  Try the below code

```
for(WebElement monthName: month_list)
    System.out.println(monthName.getText())
```

**P.S.** I doubt your Xpath ,the xpath which you wrote is the entire month calendar(that is the month name , the dates , the prices on each dates so its the entire div that you have picked)

Kindly try

```
List<WebElement> month_list= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try using,

```
List<WebElement> monthname= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']"));
```

After Storing in List of Webelements you can use different kind of for Loops for getting the text.But the best preference is forEach Loop and for Iterative Loop.

**forEach Loop:**

```
for(WebElement months: monthname)
{
    System.out.println(months.getText())
}
```

**General forLoop**

```
int length= monthname.size();

for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) 
{
    String name = monthname.get(i);
    System.out.println(name);

}
```

`PS: But The Best Preference is to go with forEachLoop Rather than General For Loop`.