# Selenium use xpath to find sub element within already acquired WebElement always returns first match on the entire page

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium and python to test a website and I'm trying to get the link to the files on the site as follows:
Use `divs = find_elements_by_css_selector("div.answer")` to get the posts on the page, this works fine.
Use `divs[i].find_element_by_xpath("//figure/a[1]").get_attribute("href)` on each of the resulting elements from the last fetch.
The site that I'm working on has this structure:

```
<html>
<div class="answer">
<blockquote class="message">
<figure class="thumb">
<a href="cdn.xyz.net/img1.jpg">
<img class="file-data" src="cdn.xyz.net/img1.jpg">
</a>
</figure>
</blockquote>
</div>
...... More identical divs with different thumbnails
</html>
```

The problem here is that the `divs[i].find_element_by_xpath("//figure/a[1]").get_attribute("href")` line always returns the first url of all the divs on the site in every iteration of the loop, in this case `cdn.xyz.net/img1.jpg` and this is not something that I'm trying to do as I would like to get the link for each div. My code that reproduces this problem is this:

```
try:
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.answer')
    for el in elements: #For every reply
        embedLink = el.find_element_by_xpath("//figure[1]/a[1]")
        print("Found embed link: " + embedLink.get_attribute("href")) #this returns the first link every time
except:
    print("error")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xapth` is searching from the root element, unless you tell it to start from current context using `.//`

```
el.find_element_by_xpath('.//figure[1]/a[1]')
```

You can also use the complete `xpath` to locate the elements

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="answer"]//figure[1]/a[1]')
for el in elements: #For every reply
    print('Found embed link: ' + el.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks, just as I thought this was a very small error in my code, I did not find this information on the internet as everyone seems to use the whole site search without the leading `.` when using `xpath`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
embedLink = el.find_element_by_xpath("//figure[1]/a[1]")
```

selects *globally* all elements `figure` and takes the first one and from this, the first `a` element.

Solution:
Add a dot in front of the `//` to start searching for elements at the current node.

```
embedLink = el.find_element_by_xpath(".//figure[1]/a[1]")
```

See also [this SO answer: "What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606964/1305969).