# How to iterate over an XML nodeset with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a very large OData XML document I'm parsing with Ruby and Nokogiri. There are multiple nodes with sub-nodes for enumerations that I want to pull into a hash.

I'm correctly finding and iterating over these nodes using:

```
data_xml.xpath('//Schema/EnumType').each do |enumerations|
    enumerations.xpath('//Annotation/@String').each do |enum|
       # add to my hash
```

I assumed by doing the second, nested, XPath search on the `enumerations` node set it'd only iterate over this specific node set, but the hash has every single annotation in the document, not just the ones in the node set.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a different way to apply XPath only to that sub-set?

Comment: Putting `//` at the beginning makes the xpath pattern absolute, so it doesn't "respect" the nesting. Try `enumerations.xpath('Annotation/@String')` or, better, `enumerations.xpath('.//Annotation/@String')` instead...

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov thank you! Please add that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: See the "descendant-or-self axis (//*)" section in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608304/128421, which discusses the various ways XPath anchors selectors.