# Why am I getting different results on the same WebElement in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

From the link (https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/22773/nz-vs-ind-1st-t20i-india-tour-of-new-zealand-2020) I want to print data from India innings. Why am I getting different results when I use XPath and cssSelector on WebElement (rows)?

Code using XPath as selector:

```
package basic;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //div[@id='innings_2']/div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr']
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\AW5044309\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/22773/nz-vs-ind-1st-t20i-india-tour-of-new-zealand-2020");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_2']/div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr']"));

         List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']"));

    for(WebElement a: rows) {
        System.out.println(a.getText());
    }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Guptill c Rohit b Shivam Dube30 19 4 1 157.89
Munro c Chahal b SN Thaku 59 42 6 2 140.48
Williamson (c) c Kohli b Chahal 51 26 4 4 196.15
de Grandhomme c Shivam Dube b Ravindra Jadeja 0 2 0 0 0.00
Ross Taylor
not out
54
27
3
3
200.00
Seifert (wk)
c Shreyas Iyer b Bumrah
1
2
0
0
50.00
Santner
not out
2
2
0
0
100.00
Extras
6
 (b 0, lb 1, w 5, nb 0, p 0)
Total
203
 (5 wkts, 20 Ov)
Did not Bat
Tickner, Southee, Ish Sodhi, Bennett
Rohit Sharma
c Ross Taylor b Santner
7
6
0
1
116.67
Lokesh Rahul (wk)
c Southee b Ish Sodhi
56
27
4
3
207.41
Virat Kohli (c)
c Guptill b Tickner
45
32
3
1
140.62
Shreyas Iyer
not out
58
29
5
3
200.00
Shivam Dube
c Southee b Ish Sodhi
13
9
1
1
144.44
Manish Pandey
not out
14
12
0
1
116.67
Extras
11
 (b 0, lb 0, w 10, nb 1, p 0)
Total
204
 (4 wkts, 19 Ov)
Did not Bat
Ravindra Jadeja, Shardul Thakur, Mohammed Shami, Yuzvendra Chahal, Jasprit Bumrah
```

CODE using cssSelector:

```
package basic;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //div[@id='innings_2']/div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr']
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\AW5044309\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/22773/nz-vs-ind-1st-t20i-india-tour-of-new-zealand-2020");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='innings_2']/div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-ltst-wgt-hdr']"));

         List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']"));

    for(WebElement a: rows) {
        System.out.println(a.getText());
    }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Rohit Sharma
c Ross Taylor b Santner
7
6
0
1
116.67
Lokesh Rahul (wk)
c Southee b Ish Sodhi
56
27
4
3
207.41
Virat Kohli (c)
c Guptill b Tickner
45
32
3
1
140.62
Shreyas Iyer
not out
58
29
5
3
200.00
Shivam Dube
c Southee b Ish Sodhi
13
9
1
1
144.44
Manish Pandey
not out
14
12
0
1
116.67
Extras
11
 (b 0, lb 0, w 10, nb 1, p 0)
Total
204
 (4 wkts, 19 Ov)
Did not Bat
Ravindra Jadeja, Shardul Thakur, Mohammed Shami, Yuzvendra Chahal, Jasprit Bumrah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching an element in another element using xpath it is important to add `.` at the starting of xpath. Use below code

```
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']"));
```

The `.` at the beginning means, that the current processing starts at the current node.

> What if we don't use dot at the start what it signifies?

Then you'd select all element nodes with matching xpath `//div[@class='cb-col cb-col-100 cb-scrd-itms']` in the whole document. (which is happening in current scenario)

Look out some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/5097027) and [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2142-using-and-expressions-in-xpath-xml-search-directives-in-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me clearing my concept.