# Selenium returns wrong element, selects first sibling element instead of looking in the element itself

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm attempting to iterate though a list of elements and print the text, however when I select an element an inside of another element, selenium returns the element inside the first sibling element and *NOT* the element inside of the element I'm actually interested in which is just, incredibly odd and frustrating.
https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-science-with-a-year-in-industry-bsc/54983514
This is the website I'm trying to scrape from, and I'm looking at the modules section.
The key part of my code:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument('--headless')

driver = Chrome(executable_path = 'D:\Programs\Python\chromedriver.exe', options = opts)

driver.get("https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/courses/details/computing-science-with-a-year-in-industry-bsc/54983514")

closeButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='closeFilter']")
closeButton.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='acceptCookie']").click()

modules_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-sub-sec='Modules']").find_element_by_class_name("cdsb_rt")
numberOfModulesByYear = len(modules_container.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdldv']"))
previousNumberOfModules = 0

for moduleYear in range(numberOfModulesByYear):
      moduleYearButtonString = "//div[@class='mdldv' and @data-module-sections='{}']".format(str(moduleYear))
      module_year = modules_container.find_element_by_xpath(moduleYearButtonString)
      module_year_a = module_year.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      while module_year_a.find_element_by_tag_name("span").get_attribute("class") == "icon icon-add": 
            module_year_a.click()
      while len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")) - previousNumberOfModules == 0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
      listOfModules = module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']")
      previousNumberOfModules = len(module_year.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mdiv']"))
      for _, module in enumerate(listOfModules):
            print(module.find_element_by_tag_name("a").find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='mdltxt']").get_attribute("outerHTML"))
      print("\n")
```

The output I get is:

```
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>


<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>


<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>


<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
```

This doesn't make any sense to me? as when I check the a element HTML it shows the *correct* name but when I try to access it via the xpath function it returns the wrong one?
Can anyone help figure out why this happens? It seems *incredibly* unintuitive if this is the intended behaviour.

Edit:
For anyone potentially reading this in the future, I did more research on xpath and after looking at way too websites explaining this, if you want to look at the current node, and *only* the current node child elements, start the xpath with `".//"` , the fullstop means it will only look at that element and the // means it's relative (or so I believe)
Not an xpath problem, just a simple formatting problem which can be scary to people who are new to this kind of stuff. best of luck to everyone doing this!

Explanations: [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath/35606964)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with relative xpaths? I'm not quite sure. But when I use the class name to find the element it works:

```py
print(module.find_element_by_tag_name("a").find_element_by_class_name('mdltxt').get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```

```
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Database Systems (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Web-Based Programming (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Systems Development (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Computing Principles (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Database Systems (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Web-Based Programming (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Systems Development (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Computing Principles (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Software Engineering 1 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Programming 2 (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Architectures and Operating Systems (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Data Structures and Algorithms (20 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Year in Industry (80 credits) - Core</span>
<span class="mdltxt">Industrial Project Report (40 credits) - Core</span>
```

Comment: this is a very stange issue, but after delving into xpaths a little more just adding a fullstop to the beginning seems to fix the issue! but this does help, thank you