# How iteratively use xpath on a scrapy.selector.unified.SelectorList?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

Let's say I have the following page structure:

[image]

Within that structure I have the following nested structure:

[image]

I wrote

```
offers = response.xpath('//li[@class = "search-page__result"]')
```

to try and create an inerrable list. This part is successful, I believe, because if I say

```
for offer in offers:
    print(offer.get())
```

then it will print out the HTML subsection as a string.

However if I say

```
for offer in offers:
    features = offer.xpath('//ul[@class = "listing-key-specs"]')
```

the content of `features` looks as if I would have used `response` instead of `offer`.

Does anyone have any guidance on how I can use xpath iteratively on each subsection of the structure at a time?

EDIT: I wanted to add this alternative solution that I found before my question was answered. As suggested [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2206) by YohanObadia, the below will work too:

```
for offer in offers:
    features = Selector(text = offer.extract()).xpath('//ul[@class = "listing-key-specs"]')
```

Comment: // means your context is the root again. Just put a dot in front of the slashes and the context is offer.

Comment: Hi @SiebeJongebloed ! Thank you for the help. That worked. Can you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? I have found one more solution on the internet and will append it to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` means your context is the root again. Just put a dot in front of the slashes and the context is offer.

```
for offer in offers:
    features = offer.xpath('.//ul[@class = "listing-key-specs"]')
```

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608304/3710053) that explains it.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.