# Xpath - I only get 1 element back even - the inspector tools shows 7

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to loop over a Xpath in Scrapy which looks like this:

```
for entry in response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@id="Content"]//div[@id="programDetails"]//div[@id="selfReportedProgramDetails"]//div[@id="hoursOfOperation"]//span[@class="hoursItem"]//span[@class="times"]/text())'):

   print(entry.get())
   print(len(response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@id="Content"]//div[@id="programDetails"]//div[@id="selfReportedProgramDetails"]//div[@id="hoursOfOperation"]//span[@class="hoursItem"]//span[@class="times"]/text())')))
```

The result looks like this

```
9:00 AM to 12:00 PM

1
```

The weird thing is, that I in my browser inspector tools, it shows me 7 childs, each weekday one child.

[image]

So why do I get only one result? I want to extract all weekdays.
I don't understand my error, maybe you'll have a hint which brings me the right way.

Cheers!

//After the hint, I use the following code:

```
for entry in response.xpath('//div[@id="Content"]//div[@id="programDetails"]//div[@id="selfReportedProgramDetails"]//div[@id="hoursOfOperation"]//span[@class="hoursItem"]'):
   print(entry.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="times"])').get())
```

Now I get 7 results, but always the `9:00 AM to 12:00 PM` which is the first one.

Comment: normalize-space() creates one item. Don't use that if you expect more results

Comment: Thats @SiebeJongebloed. So now I changed the code, but apperently I get 7 times the same element. I edited my question slightly.

Comment: Put a dot in fornt of the escond xpath like this: 
print(entry.xpath('normalize-space(.//span[@class="times"])').get())

Comment: Cheers! That was it. @SiebeJongebloed
If you could explain it in an answer I would highly appreciate it and accept it for sure as the best answer! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this XPath:

`'normalize-space(//div[@id="Content"]//div[@id="programDetails"]//div[@id="selfReportedProgramDetails"]//div[@id="hoursOfOperation"]//span[@class="hoursItem"]//span[@class="times"]/text())')`:

will give only one result because of the [`normalize-space()`](https://www.altova.com/xpath-xquery-reference/fn-normalize-space) function with all whitespace collapsed.

So to get the actual text-nodes for those spans remove the normalize-space around your XPath.

The second XPath starts with double slash, meaning, it will search from the root all nodes. To search from current context use the `.`

for more info on // vs .// see [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35608304/3710053)