# Selenium CSS Selector get only first element while the inspector show 4

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to automize Linguee dictionary using Selenium.

[image: Search of de]

For instance, in the image I would like to get an array with [de, para, por, con]. In order to get this, I wrote the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s=Service(r"C:\Users\Usuario\python\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)

driver.get('https://www.linguee.fr/frances-espanol/')
consent_button=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='sn-b-def sn-blue']")
consent_button.click()


search_input=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='queryinput']")
search_input.send_keys("de")

buttonSearch=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[alt='Rechercher dans le dictionnaire français-espagnol']")
buttonSearch.click()

wortType=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='tag_wordtype']").text
print( wortType)

translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']").text
print(translations)
```

The code work correctly, but it returns only the first translations ("en" in the image) while in the browser console I get 4. So, I have been reading and trying differents ways of fix the problem, like change the CSS_SELECTOR

```
translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='isMainTerm'] div[class='exact'] div[class='lemma featured'] div[class='lemma_content'] div[gid=0] div[class='translation_lines'] div[class='translation sortablemg featured'] a")
translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']").text
translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']")
translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.isMainTerm div.lemma_content a.dictLink").text
translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='isMainTerm']> a[class='dictLink featured']").text
```

I have also used XPath but also returns only one.
I have read differents post in stackoverflow with similar problems like this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921583/xpath-i-only-get-1-element-back-even-the-inspector-tools-shows-7), but the problem persists.

Sorry this is long-winded, but can someone guide me to why it's doing this and what my options are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `find_element` method works.
It returns the **first** matching element on the DOM it finds.
So in case you are passing it locator matching several elements on the page the first matching element on the DOM will be returned.
In case you want to get **all** the elements matching that locator `find_elements` method should be used instead.
So, in case you want to get all the texts in elements matching `div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']` CSS Selector instead of

```py
translations=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']").text
print(translations)
```

You can use

```py
translations = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']")
for translation in translations:
    print(translation.text)
```

BTW, it is only this CSS Selector locator `div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink featured']` is matching 4 elements as you mentioned and it looks like this locator you should use here while `div[class='isMainTerm'] a[class='dictLink']` locator is matching 81 elements! on that page.

Comment: Your are right in everything. Furthermore I change the CSS_Selector for translations=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.isMainTerm div.exact div.translation.sortablemg.featured a.dictLink"), and work correctly. Thanks!

Comment: You are more than welcome :) I'm happy I could help you!