# Selenium CSS Selector get only first element. How to retrieve all the elements

Tags: java, spring, selenium, web-scraping

[image]

[image]

Getting only one review using the cssSelector. Need to extract all the element of div.

```
public void getFacebookData()
{
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=AffEX_j6PH-bDCZt13fmzFUMnE49egOV7IU-LhSi3jQAof5FGyuyPmrV48JQ-DjXrgm2fzxsvhC5L6NOWURamMZiNxooPxopmjtkYs2fn5yNzg&smuh=49385&lh=Ac9lhVHRV5hDKKho4Fw");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        driver.get(FACEBOOKURL);
        final WebElement  totalRatings = driver.findElement(By.className("p8bdhjjv"));
        System.out.println("total ratings "+totalRatings.getText()); 
        final List<WebElement>  facebookReview = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='g4tp4svg mfclru0v om3e55n1 p8bdhjjv']"));
        System.out.println("size of facebook review list "+facebookReview.size());
        
        facebookReview.forEach(review -> {
            System.out.print("reviews are: "+review.getText());
            
            
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please share your code as text, not as picture

Comment: Generally for reviews, it is lazy page loading, you need to scroll down to bottom of the page and then get the count.

Comment: @Prophet added the code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'g4tp4svg') and contains(@class, 'mfclru0v') and contains(@class, 'om3e55n1') and contains(@class, 'p8bdhjjv')]"))
```

however, it might be slower than the css selector, since the xpath is (in theory) the slowest one

Comment: using this also it only takes first review. Not able to get all the elements having the same class

Comment: are all elements displayed, when selenium is trying to find them? perhaps your page isn't fully loaded and only 1 is displayed, when you're trying to collect them

Comment: I checked on the google, as per that, cssSelector only take first element of that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548292/selenium-css-selector-get-only-first-element-while-the-inspector-show-4


For instance I also try:-

   `final List<WebElement>  facebookReview = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".g4tp4svg.mfclru0v.om3e55n1.p8bdhjjv'));`