# Greater Than Condition in For-Each Select Clause XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to set the condition when price is greater than 100 or less than 50 it should output, however with the following condition I am getting all results outputted.

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//G_1/Product[.//PRICE >'100' or .//PRICE <'50' ]"><?PRICE?></xsl:for-each>
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DATA_DS>
    <G_1>
        <Product>
            <OBJECT_ACTION_ID>79071819</OBJECT_ACTION_ID>
            <Details>
                <ID>170057541</ID>
                <NAME>ITEM NAME</NAME>
            </Details>
            <Rec>
                <Rec1>
                    <Rec_Detail>
                        <C_Product_ID>300000155370949</C_Product_ID>
                        <PRICE>200</PRICE>
                    </Rec_Detail>
                </Rec1>
            </Rec>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <OBJECT_ACTION_ID>79071820</OBJECT_ACTION_ID>
            <Details>
                <ID>170057542</ID>
                <NAME>ITEM NAME2</NAME>
            </Details>
            <Rec>
                <Rec1>
                    <Rec_Detail>
                        <C_Product_ID>300000155370950</C_Product_ID>
                        <PRICE>90</PRICE>
                    </Rec_Detail>
                </Rec1>
            </Rec>
        </Product>
    </G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Note that the code you show should produce an error because `<` is  reserved character. Also `<?PRICE?>` is a processing instruction and will not create any output. And if you want the comparison to be numerical, then do not put quotes around the numbers.

Comment: added the xml, I tried to replace > with &gt; as well but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Add the expected output too. -- P.S. The problem is not with `>` but with `<`.

Comment: Does your query produce an incorrect answer with this XML? If not, please show us an XML where it does produce an incorrect answer. You say you are "getting all results outputted" -- ie presumably all products -- but there is only one product here, and it should be selected, so that's the expected result.

Comment: Updated xml to include the other record it also outputs.

Comment: We are not making progress here. Please post a [mcve] showing an XML, a complete, executable XSLT and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your output is probably correct (as in "what you requested"). In your expression you used the `.//` axis as a prefix for all of your conditions. But you'd better use them only in the predicate. Have a look at [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606964/1305969).

So, to make your XSLT/XPath probably work, change it to

```
<xsl:for-each select="//G_1/Product[.//PRICE > 100 or 50 > .//PRICE]">YOUR OUTPUT</xsl:for-each>
```

This will match - and iterate over all matches - if any`PRICE` descendant of any `G_1/Product` element has a value below 50 or above 100. I changed the predicate (the condition between `[` and `]`) in a non-obvious way to avoid the usage of the `<` character, because it is invalid in predicate expressions. Therefore I changed `PRICE < 50` to `50 > PRICE` - that's all, nothing special.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the updated code, however now it does not output any rows even when over 100.

Comment: @user1660680: I changed my answer to better fit you requirements.

Comment: when I remove the quotes around the integers it gives me an error: XML-23029: (Error) FORG0001: invalid value for cast/constructor