# Element <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log In"> is not clickable at point (674, 381)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**HTML :**

```
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Log In">
```

**Code  :**
This is the code of selenium.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']")).click();

I have to click this input

Comment: What's the context around "tried for 10 seconds with 500 milliseconds interval"? I'd move this bit of the text from the title and clarify it with additional info in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is wrong

this

```
input[@value='Log In']
```

should be

```
//input[@value='Log In']
```

Like this

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Log In']")).click();
```

`//input` selects all `input` elements in a `document`. Please read about it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath/35608304)

Comment: Element <input class="button" type="submit" value="Log In"> is not clickable at point (674, 381). Other element would receive the click: <div class="spinner">...</div> @cruisepandey

Comment: That's a different issue, not the one you've mentioned in your original question, Please try to submit a new ticket for new issue.