# XSLT generate-id() inside a predicate does not work

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using the `generate-id()` function inside a predicate to compare with a previously generated id. But this does not work and I can't figure out why.

I've created a sample XSLT with input and expected output. Yes I know - this code does seems weird and does not make sense, it is just to find out, why the `generate-id()` does not work here.

The problem line is the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="a[generate-id(current())=$a_id]/text()"/>
```

This does not work. Here the complete XML input, XSLT and expected output.

XML Input:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>3</a>
    </test>
</root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <a>1</a>
    </test>
    <test>
        <a>2</a>
    </test>
    <test>
        <a>3</a>
    </test>
</root>
```

Result Output (the values are not found with the id search):

```
<root>
    <test>
        <a/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <a/>
    </test>
    <test>
        <a/>
    </test>
</root>
```

Here is the XSLT. The problem is in the last template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>    

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="test"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".." mode="output">
                <xsl:with-param name="a_id" select="generate-id()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test" mode="output">
        <xsl:param name="a_id"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:element name="a">
                <!-- Here the passed a_id cannot be found -->
                <xsl:value-of select="a[generate-id(current())=$a_id]/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>            
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `template match="test"`, the `current()` function selects that matched `test` so I think you simply want

```
a[generate-id(.)=$a_id]
```

to make sure you compare the id of the `a` elements and not of the `test` with the `a` element. Note also that in XSLT 2.0 there is an `is` operator so you don't need to pass around ids and compare them, you could pass around the element directly and output it, or, if you need to compare some nodes based on identity, use that `is` operator.

Comment: create hint with the `is` operator. Works great too. Don't use the generate-id() anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that you need to do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="a[generate-id(.)=$a_id]/text()"/>
```

Or even this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="a[generate-id()=$a_id]/text()"/>
```

`current()` refers the the current node being matched, which is the `test` node. `.` refers the the current context (the `a` node). See [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath) for more details.

Another answer would be that you may have over-complicated things. You could re-write your XSLT as this instead..

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>    

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="test"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <test>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
            </test>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```