# XSLT Refer to the current node of a template within for-each

Tags: xslt

how can I refer to the current node matched by a template, within a `for-each` loop.

```
<xsl:template match="product[@category='foo']">
    <count>
        <xsl:for-each select="preceding::product">
                <current>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(current()/preceding::product)"/>
                </current>
                <context>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding::product)"/>
                </context>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </count>
</xsl:template>
```

Both `count()` functions return the same results with `.` as well as `current()`.

Is there a way to refer to the matched node of the template, in order to count all the preceding nodes of it, so that the result of the `count()` function inside `<current/>` is the same for every `for-each` step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the current node in a variable....

```
<xsl:template match="product[@category='foo']">
    <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
    <count>
        <xsl:for-each select="preceding::product">
                <current>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count($current/preceding::product)"/>
                </current>
                <context>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding::product)"/>
                </context>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </count>
</xsl:template>
```

In this example though, you would be better place putting the results of the count in a variable though...

Put the current node in a variable....

```
<xsl:template match="product[@category='foo']">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(preceding::product)" />
    <count>
        <xsl:for-each select="preceding::product">
                <current>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                </current>
                <context>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding::product)"/>
                </context>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </count>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! So the difference between current and context only matters within a neseted XPath-Expression?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath