# XSLT for-each loop iterating through 2 elements with same name but different attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

Note: Solution should be in XSLt 1.0

I'm a complete novice with XSLT so apologies if solutions to other questions relating to loops would work for my problem but I've had no luck so far.

I have an XML file with multiple nodes such as the following:

```
<Roles>
  <field name="linecode" instance="1" value="EY"/>
  <field name="number" instance="1" value="265"/>
  <field name="linecode" instance="2" value="PK"/>
  <field name="number" instance="2" value="123"/>
  <field name="abc" instance="1" value="123"/>
  <field name="xyz" instance="1" value="123"/>
</Role>
```

I need to loop through these nodes and print `<field name="linecode">` along with its matching instance no `<field name="number">`. However, if I use a for-each loop it will iterate through the `<field name="linecode">s` fine but print the same `<field name="number">` is not working.

Is there any way I can sync them up so that, for example the output will be

```
EY - 265
PK - 123
```

I have also tried to use the `following-sibling` but its not working for me.. Any help is highly appreciated. .

Here's my sample xslt.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="Roles">
    <xsl:for-each select="field[@name='linecode']">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='number' and instance='@instance']"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If anyone could think an alternative to loops which would work as well I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you want is this..

```
<xsl:value-of select="../field[@name='number' and @instance=current()/@instance]/@value"/>
```

Note the use of `../` at the start. If you did just `<xsl:value-of select="field.." />` you would be trying to select a child element called `field` when you are already positioned on a `field` element. Doing `..` selects the parent node first, allowing you to select a sibling element.

Also note the use of `current()` which refers to the node you are currently positioned on (the one you select with `xsl:for-each`). Read up on "current node vs context node" here: [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath)

Alternatively, you could learn about using keys here. You could define a key to look up `field` elements by their `instance` attribute

```
<xsl:key name="fields" match="field" use="@instance" />
```

So, to look up the element you do this..

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('fields', @instance)[@name = 'number']/@value"/>
```

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="fields" match="field" use="@instance" />

<xsl:template match="Roles">
    <xsl:for-each select="field[@name='linecode']">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('fields', @instance)[@name = 'number']/@value"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "matching instance" you mean the immediately following field element, then you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::field[1]/@value"/>
```

But if "matching instance" means the number field with the same id, then use

```
<xsl:value-of select="../field[@name='number' and @instance=current()/@instance]/@value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Roles">
        <xsl:for-each select="field">
            <xsl:if test="@name='linecode'">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="@name='number'">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:for-each>
Also try it
```