# Selenium find_elements returns the same element over and over Python

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to read comments from Likedin feed by:

```py
        comments = browesr.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='comments-comments-list__comment-item comments-comment-item ember-view']")
        print(comments[0].id)
        print(comments[1].id)
        print(comments[2].id)
        print(comments[0].get_attribute("id"))
        print(comments[1].get_attribute("id"))
        print(comments[2].get_attribute("id"))
        print(comments[0].find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-control-name='comment_actor_description']").text)
        print(comments[1].find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-control-name='comment_actor_description']").text)
        print(comments[2].find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-control-name='comment_actor_description']").text)
```

Output:

```py
0.854587949237863-1
0.854587949237863-2
0.854587949237863-3
ember817
ember851
ember885
Ralph M.
out of network
3rd+
Managing Director at Intervi
Ralph M.
out of network
3rd+
Managing Director at Intervi
Ralph M.
out of network
3rd+
Managing Director at Intervi
```

As you can see the IDs are diffrent but the elements inside each one is the same one (the first one), what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace XPath

```
"//*[@data-control-name='comment_actor_description']"
```

with

```
".//*[@data-control-name='comment_actor_description']"
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Could you please explain to me the meaning of the "." in the begining?

Comment: @Omri the dot in the beginning of XPath expression stands for [*context node*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath) - `comments[0]`, `comments[1]`, ...

Answer (score -1):

You cannot find an element with XPath again if you already have a web element with you. The solution to this is to use another mechanism such as id, class, name, tagname etc.

This will work.

Comment: No. This is not true. Chaining like `driver.find_element_by_xpath(<XPath_1>).find_element_by_xpath(<XPath_2>)` works fine

Comment: Theoretically, it's true. but when you do this practically, selenium messes up the elements and you don't even get to understand the issue.