# XPath relative vs absolute tests

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I would like to better understand the meaning and usefulness of `.` before `/h3`.
I looked for a website with a tutorial, but I couldn't find one explaining its use.

```
//div[./h3/a[text()='Home']]
```

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath/35608304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that of [*relative*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-RelativeLocationPath) vs [*absolute*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) selection.

Disregarding the `/a[text()='Home']` common to both cases:

- **Relative selection:**
  `//div[./h3]` selects all `div` elements that have an `h3` child element.
  Note that it can be simplified to `//div[h3]`.
- **Absolute selection:**
  `//div[/h3]` selects all `div` elements provided that the document root element is `h3`.

Absolute tests such as `/h3` within a predicate (`[/h3]`) are relatively uncommon.

### See also

- [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1022345/290085)
- [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/290085)