# Why //descendant is evaluating siblings as well in this XSLT template?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, descendant

I am curious why this XSLT :

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//ca"/> 
      </xsl:template>
      
      
      <xsl:template match="ca">  
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:value-of select="//cd"/> 
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

over this XML document

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <!DOCTYPE a>
    <a>
      <b>
        <c>
          <ca>CA</ca>
          <cd>CD</cd>
        </c>   
      </b>  
    </a>
```

has the result:
CACD

I'm mostly interested in why  CD evaluates properly because I thought current context in a template is defined by match attribute, that is to say, *ca* in the second template.
If that was correct, in the context of *ca*, with //cd, as far as I know, the XSLT processor should be searching by any descendant of *ca* of any level with name *cd*.

*cd* is a sibling of *ca*, so I am very confused.

I would appreciate any help which sheds light on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is well-written.  Please be sure to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer (to this question and your past questions).  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.//cd` to select relative to the context node, a path starting with `/` always selects starting at the document node/root node, i.e. `//cd` is `/descendant-or-self::node()/cd`.

Comment: See also [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1022345/290085)