# What difference does a leading / (slash) make in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the difference (if exists) between the following expressions ?

1. `/descendant-or-self::node()`
2. `descendant-or-self::node()`

I don't understand what is the meaning of the `/` in this case in the beginning of the first expression.

According to the explanation from the class, the meaning of `/` is go down a level in the tree.

So how is this reflected here?

(According to checks that I did, it's seen that a difference does not exist, but I don't understand why according to the explain mentioned above given by my lecturer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that of [*absolute*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath) vs [*relative*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-RelativeLocationPath) selection.

- An XPath starting with `/` is *absolute* (based on the root node of the document).
- An XPath starting with an axis, or `./`, is *relative* to the context node.

### See also

- [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708/290085)
- [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1022345/290085)

Comment: Which means, of course, that in the common case where the context node is the same as the root node, then there is no difference between the expressions.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes, thanks for explicitly accounting for OP's observation that there were no differences in cases he checked.  JobProcessTask, a common case where the difference would manifest would be within predicates ( `[` *inside here* `]` ).