# Why is my xpath able to find the element at all?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to print text of each `div` with `class="Name"`. The code below prints `Name1` three times instead of `Name1`, `Name2` and `Name3`.

1. Why does my code print `Name1` three times?
2. Why is `dateInput.FindElement` even able to find the `Root` div at all? `Root` div is located in completely different level than the `date` element. And since I'm doing `//div...`, which means find the div in the current node (right?), on `dateInput.FindElement` it should NOT even find the `Root` div, right?

**CODE**

```
var dateInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("date"));
var rootElement = dateInput.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'Root')]"));
var boxes = rootElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'Box)]"));
foreach (var box in boxes)
{
    var nameElement = box.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'Name')]"));
    Console.WriteLine(nameElement.Text);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input id="date"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="__Root">
    <div>
      <div class="__Box">
        <div class="__Name">Name1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="__Box">
        <div class="__Name">Name2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="__Box">
        <div class="__Name">Name3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not well-formed ... but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: There's also a typo: `"//div[contains(@class,'Box)]"` should be `"//div[contains(@class,'Box')]"`

Comment: If you want to make an element search "starting from" current element you need to specify the *[context node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022345/current-node-vs-context-node-in-xslt-xpath)*: `var rootElement = dateInput.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[contains(@class,'Root')]"))`

Answer (score 1):

You are evaluating an XPath expression starting with `//` relative to a particular context node, but the meaning of `//` is to search the document from the document's root, ignoring the context node altogether (except of course that the context does provide the document which is being searched). So you execute the same query three times. Each time, your query expression matches all 3 `div` elements in the document, but because the `findElement` method is defined to return a single element, it is returning the first one each time.

To search within a subtree rooted at the context node, your expression should start with `.//`.

Secondly, you could just search directly for the "Name" `div` elements with a single XPath expression (broken onto multiple lines for readability), and simplify your c# code drastically:

```xml
//div[contains(@class,'Root')]
   //div[contains(@class,'Box')]
      //div[contains(@class,'Name')]
```

Comment: Use `.//` if you look for any descendant node of the current node, use `./` if you look for  a node which is a direct child of the current

Comment: I'm confused. So,  `//` is indeed relative to a particular context node, but it ignores it and searches from document's root?

Comment: Let me put it this way: the XPath expression is evaluated relative to a context node (because you've called the `FindElements` method of a particular node; that means that a context node _is_ provided to the XPath evaluator), but the XPath expression itself, because it starts with `/`, searches from the root of the document. The XPath expression isn't ignoring the context node altogether, though, because the document root node where the search begins is precisely the root of the document that contains the context node.

Comment: NB `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

Comment: In my mind, once `//` is used from `FindElements` the XPath should consider the context node as the root and do everything relative to that context node and not the root of the document.

Comment: Well that misconception is the root of your problem, here, obviously enough. NB it would have been a mistake for the developers of the C# XPath API to make `FindElements` construct a new document that contains the context node as its root element, and execute the XPath over that document, because that would have made it impossible to execute XPath expressions such as e.g. `ancestor::foo`, since all ancestor elements would be lost.